# Loop with $.each() and calculate the values from inputs

Tags: jquery

I am doing Add / Remove inputs fields with jquery - as shown below
what i am trying to do is when i click on `#AddInputService` button
it adds input field, then i enter a price.

when i do each loop around the inputs values i don't get any values accept the first value which has been entered in the first input field.. here is the code down below

```
<span class="tools pull-right">
<button id="AddInputService" data-toggle="button">
</button>
</span>
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>

    <th width="">Price</th>
    <th width=""><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="serviceInner">

     // ^^ inputs fields will be added here when button is clicked

    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="left">
        <span class="T">Total</span> 
        <span id="totalServices">00.00</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </tbody>
    </table>

 jQuery(document).ready(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

     //initlal count
var x = 1;
$('#AddInputService').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

// Tbody inner - 
var tbodyInner = $('#serviceInner');

    // ^^^ This is part is working - it's adding inputs :-)
$(tbodyInner).append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" class="price" placeholder="0.00"></td><td><button data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-default" id="serviceDelete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td></tr>');

        binding();
 }); // end 

$('#serviceDelete').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

$(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
        update_total_services();
}); // end

}); // end ready

function update_total_services() {
        var total = 0;
        var totalServices = $('#totalServices');

        // ^^ Something wrong here i can't get it right
        $('.price').each(function() {

            var price = $(this).val();
            total += Number(price);
        });

        totalServices.text(total+'.00');
 }

function binding() {
   $(".price").blur(update_total_services);
}
```

Comment: As of jQuery version 1.7 the .live() function is deprecated and it was removed from 1.9 and upwards (http://api.jquery.com/live/). Use .on() instead.

Comment: No it's seems that not to be working. The total remain the same..

Comment: I believe in JavaScript, the IDs have to be unique. If you have multiple elements with the same ID, it will only recognize the first one.

Comment: that's correct , sorry just learning jquery. :) i am trying to do my best..just to make it work. but i have been trying to solve it out more than 4 hours . Thanks for tip... :)

Comment: ok. now i have made .class as reference to the input field. but its not working the total remain the same..

Comment: it's, working guys now thanks for the help...i Really appricated. every one helped me out through this . THANKS AGAIN

Answer (score 1):

First, you should generate a unique id attribute for each dynamic text input. This is a good practice in general.

Second, instead of referencing the specific text input's id in your selector for .each(), reference the parent container for all text inputs.

Comment: It might be hard for me to refrence parent container. but i will change the replace the id="ServicePrice" To class="ServicePrice"

Comment: it's, working guys now thanks for the help...i Really appricated. every one helped me out through this . THANKS AGAIN